# How to prove elementary set theory problem: $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)=A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B^c$ are disjoint, with $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B^c)=A$, but I do not know how to approach it. Intuitively expressed in Venn Diagrams, the above statement is correct.

Comment: Do you allow yourself to use: $\forall x[x\in U\iff x\in V]\implies U=V$?

Comment: I was not clear on all relevant set algebra properties when I had approached this problem. I was able to follow the selected answer below once I had understood them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disjoint:
$$(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap B^c) = A\cap A\cap B\cap B^c = A\cap\emptyset = \emptyset$$
Union is $A$:
$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap B^c) = A\cap(B\cup B^c) = A$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^{c})&=[(A\cap B)\cup A]\cap [(A\cap B)\cup B^c]\nonumber\\
&=A\cap [(A\cup B^c)\cap (B\cup B^c)]\nonumber\\
&=A\cap (A\cup B^c)\nonumber\\
&=A
\end{align*}

Comment: Aside from intuitively knowing that $A \cap (A \cup B^c) = A$, is there a specific algebraic set property that you have used?

Comment: I've used $A\cap X=A$ whenever $A\subseteq X$.